# redux-saga cancel effect trigger error "is already running" while it does cancel. Or How to remove this error from the console?

Tags: reactjs, redux, generator, redux-saga

I am trying since weeks to understand why my `yield cancel` throw an error when I am trying to run a `cancel` effect in my root saga :

```
export function* loginData() {
  const watcher = yield fork(getLoginWatcher);
  yield take(LOCATION_CHANGE);
  yield cancel(watcher);
}
```

**Error in console:**

```
utils.js:202 uncaught at getLogin Generator is already running"
```

If I remove the cancel my saga doesn't get canceled. It's like working and throwing error at the same time.

Having this error really annoy me it look like there is a problem with my application.

The execution env :

- Debian 8 Jessie
- Version 54.0.2840.100 (64-bit)
- Node v7.2.0
- Npm 3.10.9

Does anyone has any information on how `redux-saga/effects` proc does handle it's `cancel` effect and **how** the **is already running** error is generated.

Comment: Would you write down the whole saga file or at least the `getLogin` generator? cause from what you've mentioned no problems in your task cancellation here

Comment: what's the execution env (versin of chrome?, node?). I asked because it could be likely a V8 bug. see https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/9372 or https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/9372

Comment: @Basim, I have uploaded the whole saga, I've posted here in pastebin. Last time I posted the whole saga file someone vote me down told me to select the relevant part of code. Also, I am sure that it comes from the cancel, and the `getLogin` is trivial: http://pastebin.com/3J97tP2a

Comment: @YassineElouafi. Both link you send me or similar. Do you know how I could be sure if it's a v8 bug

Comment: you can try with other browsers like Edge, firefox or also babel transpiled code. To follow the issue could  you send a PR to the redux-saga repo? also it would be very helpful to provide some runnable test-case or a gist/jsbin?

Comment: @YassineElouafi are you yelouafi ? Do you still need a gist ? I though your example on https://github.com/yelouafi/redux-saga/issues/703 was already reproducing the same error. I will have to wait for the test with edge firefox. I don't know about babel transpiled code test you want me to do. What pull request should I do.

Comment: you can just post a link to the gist in the repo. we know how 'could' the error happens in general but we need to know how it happens in redux-saga and thus if it's a lib error or a JS VM bug. if you can provide the gist that's sufficient, no need to for other tests

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the cause of this might not have been the cancel effect, as stated in the description. I was trying to complete a similar login process independently, using react-boilerplate, and finding a lot of the other examples were using older methods than the latest boilerplate code, so have been working through the issues and I also got this exact error, which from the call stack appeared to be coming from the cancel effect. 
However, when reading through the same issue as posted here https://github.com/react-boilerplate/react-boilerplate/issues/1281 somebody suggested that it was in fact an error being caused because 'forwardTo' was being called without using

yield call (forwardTo, params)

Once I changed calls in the sagas to this, the error went away. I assume this is the solution to the problem. Others seem to agree on the github issue page.